# Laravel Regex Validation (text should end up with .jpg or .png)

Tags: regex, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I have a laravel validation rule something like this

```
public function rules(){
   return [
            'title' => 'required|max:100',
            'featured_image' => 'required|max:100|regex:(\d)+.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)',

        ];
}
```

I have a txt field where i dynamically add an image name, something like this (8123123123.jpg OR 234234234.png). If the text field doesn't have this pattern i want to show an error.

Now this regex does work in http://regexr.com/ but in laravel it doesn't. So basically it should look for digits as file name and should end with .jpg or .png

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Something about an unknown modifier + and . I think it might be because of the reason that this regex is for javascript

Comment: Or it might be due to the pipe symbols, as laravel also follows the same pattern to separate different rules.

Comment: You need to escape the dot - like `\.`. Additionally, you might want to make sure, that the jpg/png/gif part is at the very end of the string, so combined, this would be: `\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$`

Comment: Here is what i tried ( required|max:100|regex:\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$ ) and got an error saying Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: Try `'featured_image' => array('required', 'max:100', 'regex:/[0-9]+[.](jpe?g|png|gif)/')`

Comment: Yes, that worked like a charm :)

Comment: i already did try with arrays but i guess my regex was not good enough for laravel :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this

```
'featured_image' => ['required', 'max:100', 'regex:/(\d)+.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)/']
```

You have to add a regex delimiter http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Its not a file, its just a txt field with the name of a file. File is already uploaded through an ajax request

Comment: I have my answer @omerFarooq pls check

Comment: Thanks arif but i already tried this. It gives an error saying Unknown modifier '+'. @Wiktor's method worked well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation) you should put your validations in a array:

```
regex:pattern
```

> The field under validation must match the given regular expression.
>
> Note: When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.